# Messed up .htaccess

Tags: php, html, wordpress, .htaccess

I have been messing around with .htaccess and now I cant fix it..

My website is:

```
https://crowdinvestor.org/
```

I have tried to fix that I had built the website up in html and my blog in wordpress, but it didnt go as planned.

**HTML pages:**

Invest online : `https://crowdinvestor.org/index.html`

Books : `https://crowdinvestor.org/books.html`

P2P Comparison & Offers : `https://crowdinvestor.org/offers.html`

**Wordpress blog:**

```
https://crowdinvestor.org/crowdlending-for-beginners/
```

The wordpress blog redirects to:

`https://crowdinvestor.org/crowdlending-for-beginners.html`
which isnt what I want it to.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Show us your htaccess file.

Comment: I've been messing around with it too many times, but the current one is:
`# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress`

Comment: Use the [**edit** link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54423493/edit). Also show access log, enable rewrite log, etc.

Comment: @mario I'm sorry I dont understand the question. Is there any other logs to show than the .htaccess file?

Comment: @JacobBalslev It would be useful to more explicitly say what URL is redirecting where, and where it *should* redirect to, since based on your current question I can't quite tell (fault is possibly mine!).

Comment: See also: [How to debug Apache mod\_rewrite](//stackoverflow.com/q/9632852) and [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](//stackoverflow.com/q/20563772). (I don't think there's enough explanation yet on what you really wanted to accomplish. That generic `$1.php` mapping you found is unfit for most tasks.)

Comment: And a rewrite to `.php` would not explain how you get to `/crowdlending-for-beginners.html` in the first place either … Please edit your question, and bring a little more structure into it.

Comment: My problem is that I have a blog on `https://crowdinvestor.org/crowdlending-for-beginners/` that is now redirecting to  `https://crowdinvestor.org/crowdlending-for-beginners.html` - I have somehow forced a .html extension on it, and even though it's not visible in the .htaccess file, it's still not possible to go to `https://crowdinvestor.org/crowdlending-for-beginners/`

Comment: Maybe, but surely _not_ by appending `.php` at the end, and that is about the only rewriting you have shown us so far … So, show us the complete thing.

Comment: Dude, **edit link**! And yes that very issue is caused by the rule block you added.

Comment: (And make sure your browser cache is not fooling you to begin with; some browsers cache redirects real hard, so it might sometimes look like you are experiencing a problem that doesn’t really exist any more. Test in a new private window, or clear browser history …)

Comment: Is there a way to force a reset on the .htaccess? I am able to "solve" the problem by changing the wordpress posts permalink structure from  `https://crowdinvestor.org/sample-post/` to `https://crowdinvestor.org/?p=123` but I cant remove the .html extension from the postname

Comment: I've deleted wordpress completely and did a reinstall twice.. It still forces `https://www.crowdinvestor.org/crowdlending-for-beginners/` into `https://www.crowdinvestor.org/crowdlending-for-beginners.html`